# Use a Regular expression with $cond

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to show some value on the basis of a condition.
my requirement is : if i found # in a field value then it show "ABC" else "XYZ"

my agg code is

```
 db.test.aggregation{[
  { "$project":{
    "name":  "$firstname", 
    "gender": "$gender",
    "email": "$email",
    "type": { $cond: { 
      "if": { userval": { $in: [ "/#/"] } },
      "then": "ABC",
      "else": "XYZ"
    }}
  }}
]};
```

i have to set type ABC or XYZ if field userval have "#" in it.

if any other way to doing the same, please update me, i will definitely prefer.

thanks

Comment: You would basically use an `$or` except that you want a `$regex` match, and there is no such logical operation for the aggregation framework.

Comment: @BlakesSeven any hack or crack, this is what my requirement is.

Comment: mapReduce uses JavaScript code so it can project the result of a regex as a logical condition. What is the full intent of the operation other than then `$project` stage listed above. Already stated this is not possible for the aggregation framework, so if you can change your question to instead show the problem to solve, then that might have an answer.

Comment: @BlakesSeven thanks a lot, i am updating the question